# Got an error sending email with nodejs and mailgun

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, mailgun

---

Beofre someone say that I'm doing a duplicate question, i already searched and other solutions, for me doesn't work, per example this one: [Example of the domain name for mailgun be for nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595782/example-of-the-domain-name-for-mailgun-be-for-nodejs)

I have been trying to send a email with the api of mailgun with nodejs + typescript.
I've instaled all the libraries needed, in fact everything works if I use the sandbox domain that mailgun let you use. 
The problem comes when i use the domain i have added in mailgun.
My code is this:

```
const mailer = new Mailgun({
        apiKey: api_key,
        domain: 'tresee.app'
    });
    const mensaje = {
        from: "tresee.app",
        to: "miguelmonteiroclaveri@gmail.com",
        subject: "Hello",
        html: "<b>Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!</b>"
    };
    const response = await mailer.messages().send(mensaje);
```

Este codigo, si pongo el dominio de sandbox de mailgun funciona perfectamente, pero si pongo mi dominio **tresee.app** me sale el siguiente error:

```
error Error: Domain not found: tresee.app
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\migue\Documents\proyectoFinal\auth-backend\node_modules\mailgun-js\lib\request.js:327:17)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  statusCode: 404
} 
body { message: 'Domain not found: tresee.app' }
```

In mailgun i added correctly my domain with the next dns records and still giving me the error
[image: image of domain verified]

[image: Image of all dns records asked and verified]

Anyone can explain me why i get this error message ? Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, anywhere in the documentation was this answer, just found it by luck.
Had to add the next line in the inizialization of mailgun:
`host: "api.eu.mailgun.net"`